# Sending 2d array from java program to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I have searched and searched for a solution to this, but I haven't been able to find exactly what I need.

What I need is to be able to call a java program from my javascript and return a 2d array to my js. I can get it to work by returning a 1d array from my java program, but not a 2d.

I am not that strong in js or java, but I was assigned a project working with this as we are upgrading a system we use which requires the use of these languages. We are working with wepbapps that run in Tomcat for a Voice Recognition system that handles phone calls.

Here are some of the things that I have tried.

This is where I tried to put the returned 2d array into a new var:

```
var results = cp.CallFunction("AccountRead", params);
```

I tried to create a 2d array in js and move my java 2d array to that:

```
var results = new Array();
results[0] = new Array();
results[1] = new Array();
results[2] = new Array();
results = cp.CallFunction("AccountRead", params);
```

The only thing that I can think of right now is to have my java program put each array from the 2d array into strings and then when the data gets to my js I can parse the string out, but that sounds a little cumbersome. However, I am willing to do what I have to so that I can move my data to my js.

Comment: could you post an example of what params gets populated with? how are you calling a java program from javascript and can you post a piece of the code that is calling java? can you post a piece of the java code that is returning the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and I belive the answer is ajax. I am going to set up a servlet to generate xml from my data and send it back. Then the data will be sent to a callback function to process it on the page.